# referencing a Contact's Account type

Tags: apex, account, contact

I want to reference a Contact's Account so I can do something like:

```
contact.Contact_Type__c = contact.Account__r.Type;
```

Account__r is not available of course.
How can I reference the Account to get its type in Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship from Contacts to Accounts is just `Account`. Try this:

```
[select Account.Type from Contact]
```